# Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `attachment_url' for #<#Class:0x00007f9f6098f308:0x00007f9f6493d770>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `attachment_url' for #<#Class:0x00007f9f6098f308:0x00007f9f6493d770>

Env: ruby : ruby 2.6.5p114 | Rails 6.0.2.2
what i did :

````
rails active_storage:install
rails db:migrate
has_one_attached :main_image
<%= f.label :main_image %>
<%= f.file_field :main_image %>
<%= image_tag event.main_image %>```
````

Answer (score 3):

Fixed !! 
a long time ago i had to remove all actionmailbox and activestorage routes. 
in the `config/application.rb` and that causes this problem

```
    initializer(:remove_action_mailbox_and_activestorage_routes, after: :add_routing_paths) { |app|
      app.routes_reloader.paths.delete_if {|path| path =~ /activestorage/}
      app.routes_reloader.paths.delete_if {|path| path =~ /actionmailbox/ }
    }
```

Comment: It really helps, but I am curious, what did the code doing to the project? I fork one open source code here, I am not sure, whether if I comment this code, which will cause any issues later.

Comment: Oh, mate. I faced the same issue and this solution is brilliant. Your are my saver.
p.s. I dropped my rails project a long time ago because of that issue‍♂️