# Getting error while displaying image "Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `attachment_url' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000b770>"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, rails-activestorage

Here's how my model looks like.

```
class Bug < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bug_users, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users , through: :bug_users  
    belongs_to :project
    has_one_attached :screenshot
end
```

The uploading part is working just fine but when i am displaying it in the view like this

```
<% @bugs.each do |bug| %>
<p>
   <strong>Title:</strong>
   <%= bug.title %>
</p>
<p>
<%if bug.screenshot.present? %>
   <strong>Screenshot:</strong>
   <%= image_tag bug.screenshot %>
<%end%>
</p>
<% end%>
```

[I am getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt6Ri.png)

Comment: Try : `<%= image_tag url_for(bug.screenshot) %>`

Comment: now it gives: undefined method `attachment_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x0000000000c0a8>

Comment: maybe `bug.screenshot.attached?`  return false.

Comment: Also check if it helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715426/cant-resolve-image-into-url-undefined-method-attachment-url-for-class0x0

Comment: @LamPhan nah i've tried without the if statement it still gives the same error :(

Comment: @OmerAslam I've tried it didn't work.

Comment: @AbdulHanan can you add few more details like Ruby and Rails version and did you run active_storage:install before adding relation etc.

Comment: Thanks y'all, I found out what was wrong. Actually, I forgot to add the column screenshot:attachment in my model.

Comment: @AbdulHanan please mark this question as resolved so it won't appear on other folks :)

Comment: @AbdulHanan happy you solve the issue. For benefits of others, can you elaborate how you solve this or even better if you answer your own question. As with the active_storage we don't need to add any column in the model.

Comment: @OmerAslam I don't know how to explain its kinda crazy actually i saw a tutorial in which he was generating the model like "rails g model User avatar:attachment" so i thought maybe i have to add a column in my model and when i did it gave (# Could not dump table "bugs" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'attachment' for column 'screenshot') in my schema.rb but it did resolve the error and then i again ran a migration to remove that column and surprisingly it was still not giving an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved! its kinda crazy actually i saw a tutorial in which he was generating the model like:

```
rails g model User avatar:attachment
```

So, I thought maybe i have to add a column in my model and when i did it gave:

```
# Could not dump table "bugs" because of following StandardError 
# Unknown type 'attachment' for column 'screenshot'
```

in my schema.rb but it did resolve the error and then i again ran a migration to remove that column and surprisingly it was still not giving this error.