# Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `attachment_url' for #<#<Class:0x00007fd896f12bd0>:0x00007fd89a26a000>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, rubygems, rails-activestorage

image_tag doesn't work from me for some reason.

- I have installed Active Storage gem
- I have has_many_attached :images in my Bug model
- I have tried using polymorphic_url, and url_for. It doesn't work either
- [Here is what my error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evUfj.png)

Comment: Maybe this could be solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61715426/cant-resolve-image-into-url-undefined-method-attachment-url-for-class0x0

Comment: Tried this, it didn't work for me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace image_tag like below. @bug.images is collection of activestorage objects so you need to access the image path like image.key

```
<%=image_tag(img.key)%>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It says 'asset is not present in the asset pipeline' since image_tag gives the path of assets pipeline by default. Even if i provide full path image_tag("project/storage/#{img.key}"), I see alt text and not the image. Can you help with this?

Comment: Can you access the image directly via url and you sure it is present? And what is the url that is created when you do image tag img

Comment: Try doing this and see if the path is coming up correctly when you use this feature https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#displaying-images-videos-and-pdfs It will lead you to why the path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I got done with my task by using cloudinary with active storage, and using its image tag like this:

> <%if @bug.bug_screenshot.attached? %>   <%=
> cl_image_tag(@bug.bug_screenshot.key, width: 300, height: 300)%> <%
> end %>